# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$Null cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: json, spring

Exception is `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `org.json.JSONObject$Null` cannot be cast to `java.lang.String`

`Printthis>>>>>>userName=user1&passKey=12345678
POST Response Code :: 200`

`jsonObj>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>{"response":{"roleTitle":"Parent","roleId":146,"passKey":"12345678","id":1,"userName":"user1"},"errorCode":null,"error":false,"message":null}`

`Jan 04, 2018 4:33:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context with path [/balihans] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$Null cannot be cast to java.lang.String] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$Null cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.swasth.general.controller.SwasthController.postLogin(SwasthController.java:2274)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

**Here is my postLogin code**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postLogin(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletRequest response) throws IOException, JSONException {

    ModelAndView addmodel = new ModelAndView("login");
    String uri = "http://localhost:8080/login/api/";
    URL url = new URL(uri);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String passKey = request.getParameter("passKey");
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

    os.write(("userName=" + userName + "&passKey=" + passKey).getBytes());
    System.out.println("Printthis>>>>>>" + "userName=" + userName + "&passKey=" + passKey);
    os.flush();
    os.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);        

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer responses = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        responses.append(inputLine);
    }
    //System.out.println("responses>>>>>>>>>>>"+responses);

    String str = responses.toString();
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(str);

    System.out.println("jsonObj>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+jsonObj);

    String res = (String)jsonObj.get("errorCode");

    // build a JSON object

    List<PatentLoginInfo> PatentLoginInfoArray = new ArrayList<PatentLoginInfo>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String res11 = (String)jsonObj.get("response");
    String login = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(login);
    JSONObject objects = obj.getJSONObject(res11);

    System.out.println("objects>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+objects);

    PatentLoginInfo patentLoginInfo = mapper.readValue(objects.toString(), PatentLoginInfo.class);
     PatentLoginInfoArray.add(patentLoginInfo);

    addmodel.addObject("theLogin", PatentLoginInfoArray);

    if (res.equals("BVE000403")) { // success

        addmodel = new ModelAndView("index");
        addmodel.addObject("login Unsucessfull","Password is invalid");

        return addmodel;
    } 
    else{

            addmodel = new ModelAndView("AnswerQuestion");
            addmodel.addObject("login sucessfull");
            return addmodel;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please see [Minimal, Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question, so it is more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 13):

JSONObject has a specific inner constant for representing null objects: `JSONObject.NULL`

Before casting your JSONObject to a String, you may verify if it equals the NULL constant. Here an example:

```
//put words from JSON to array
for (int i = 0; i<wordsInJSONArray.length(); i++) {
    Object o = wordsInJSONArray.get(i);
    if (!JSONObject.NULL.equals(o)) {
        String word = (String) o;
        this.wordsArray[i] = word;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could one use `==` instead of `.equals()`? If `JSONObject.NULL` constant is represented by a single `Object`, then, all null objects in json would reference that object, wouldn't they?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use isNull()

Returns true if the associated value for the specified name is JsonValue.NULL. More [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.glassfish/javax.json/1.0.3/javax/json/JsonObject.html)

So your code would be:

`String code = jsonObj.isNull("errorCode") ? "" : jsonObj.getJsonString("errorCode");`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `"errorCode"` is null from your print :

```
{"roleTitle":"Parent","roleId":146,"passKey":"12345678","id":1,"userName":"user1"},"errorCode":null,"error":false,"message":null}
```

So you need to check on null before casting to string

`String res = (String)jsonObj.get("errorCode");`

so apply the following validation and it will work :

```
String res = null;
if (!org.json.JSONObject.NULL.equals(jsonObj.opt("errorCode")) && jsonObj.getString("errorCode") != null) {
    res = jsonObj.getString("errorCode");
}
```